# running stanford corenlp server on existing ftp webspace

Tags: php, server, ftp, stanford-nlp

I have been doing stuff with Stanford CoreNLP.
What I have to do is to use PHP and Stanford CoreNLP PHP Adapter for analyzing articles scraped with certain keywords from Google.
I want to make the process server-side.

I have been trying the Stanford CoreNLP Server, but what I can do with it is running a server on a local computer only.
Are there any ways to implement the Stanford CoreNLP function server-side on my existing FTP server, so that my website users can be benefited from the NLP?

- I do not want to use the Stanford CoreNLP HTTP API, cause it is not stable and my work may cause intensive loads to it.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm unclear on what this is asking. Would you like to call CoreNLP (a Java program) from PHP without going through the HTTP API?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. You are partly correct. The Stanford CoreNLP PHP Adapter (php) applied CoreNLP functions and gives results as JSON through Stanford's online API service or a localhost server that I set following the Stanford's guide. I want to apply the Adapter in my website, but both the online API service (unstable and may cause intensive loads) and the localhost method (can't be applied in the website) are not the suitable ways.

Comment: https://github.com/DennisDeSwart/php-stanford-corenlp-adapter

Comment: It would be great if the API service can be installed in my server where my website is stored.

Comment: Would running the server on your own machines work, as described here? https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html

Comment: It would not work as my machine would not be running for a long period of time. What I need to do is to change " define('ONLINE_URL' , 'http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process?outputFormat=json&Process=Submit&input='); " with replacing the front part by my website address. My web hosting service is provided by Laughing Squid, and they only provide service through Linux server without Shell access and external software installation in server is forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of CoreNLP adapter, my comments:

- Try getting a Virtual Private Server (VPS). Then you can install whatever you want. You will need to install Java and PHP.
- Try install CoreNLP server like Gabor said.
- Do not use the ONLINE setting: this was meant only for Stanford.edu
- Change the localhost setting instead: point it to where CoreNLP Server is installed on your VPS

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though I have finally decided to use Gdelt database instead of using NLP to analyse articles. Gdelt has already done lots already and makes me skip the part of language processing. Thanks anyway.